# 2 servers, 2 memory tables, different sizes

Tags: mysql, memory-table

I have got two servers both running a MySQL instance. The first one, server1, is running MySQL 5.0.22. The other one, server2, is running MySQL 5.1.58.

When I create a memory table on `server1` and I add a row its size is instantly `8,190.0 KiB`.

When I create a memory table on `server2` and I add a row its size is still only `some bytes`, though.

Is this caused by the difference in MySQL version or (hopefully) is this due to some setting I can change?

EDIT:

I haven't found the reason for this behaviour yet, but I did found a workaround. So, for future references, this is what fixed it for me:

All my memory tables are made once and are read-only from thereon. When you specify to MySQL the maximum number of rows your table will have, its size will shrink. The following query will do that for you.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MAX_ROWS = N
```

Comment: Can you provide the table structure?

Comment: The problem even exists when I've got only one column called for example id (smallint)

Comment: Do the servers have the same architecture? I mean 32 / 64 bits

Comment: No, they don't. Server1 is 64 bits and server2 is 64 bits. This would only account for a difference in size of maximum a factor 2, though.

Answer (score 0):

Factor of 2?

OK, the problem likely is caused by the UTF-8 vs latin1
:- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

You can check the database connection, database default character set for both servers.

here is the testing I have just done :-

```
mysql> create table test ( name varchar(10) ) engine
    -> =memory;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)

mysql> show create table test;
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                   |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| test  | CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `name` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into test values ( 1 );

mysql> set names utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)


mysql> create table test2 ( name varchar(10) ) engine =memory default charset = utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> insert into test2 values ( convert(1 using utf8) );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> select table_name, avg_row_length from information_schema.tables where TABLE_NAME in( 'test2', 'test');
+------------+----------------+
| table_name | avg_row_length |
+------------+----------------+
| test       |             12 |
| test2      |             32 |
+------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: The factor 2 is the difference in size that can be caused by using a different architecture, as can be seen in:
SUM_OVER_ALL_BTREE_KEYS(max_length_of_key + sizeof(char*) × 4)
+ SUM_OVER_ALL_HASH_KEYS(sizeof(char*) × 2)
+ ALIGN(length_of_row+1, sizeof(char*))

Where char* is 4 on 32 bit systems and 8 on 64 bit systems. The difference in size in my case is much bigger, though. Moreover it is because mysql is reserving a lot of memory for the memory table. When I set MAX_ROWS to a lower value, the size shrinks, while the data stays the same. 

Thank you for your effort, though.